# Joining a directory name with a binary file name

Tags: python, directory

I want to `os.path.join` a directory with a file name. The file it's binary and has no extension. 
The result is always like: 
`'C:\\directory\\filename\n'` 
What I want is of course: 
`'C:\\directory\\filename'` 
Without the the last backslash and the `n`, i.e. `\n`. 
My code is:

```
self.filePath = os.path.join(self.cwd, self.values[index])
```

How can I get the desired result?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Does the binary you are trying to join have a newline after it? What if you try 
`os.path.join(basepath,binary.rstrip())`

Comment: Cannot reproduce: `os.path.join('c:\path', 'foo')` --> `'c:\\path\\foo'`

Comment: What does the output of print(repr(binary)) look like?

Comment: @Mureinik I updated my question to include the code.

Comment: It's probably the last character in  `self.values[index]`. You should find out where it's coming from and try to eliminate it. One way to remove trailing whitespace would be with `self.values[index].rstrip()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = 'C:\\directory\\filename\n'
s2 = s[:-1]
print(s2)
```

leads to:

```
'C:\\directory\\filename'
```

Comment: This was the fastest way to get where I wanted to!
I will also consider the other answers for other cases.

Comment: Consider that this is treating the symptoms and not identifying the cause of the issue. You may want to look into why your binary value has a newline character at the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

An efficient way which is os independent is to use `os.sep` like below:

```
import os
filepath = os.path.join("C:", os.sep, "directory", "filename")
print(filepath)
```

Output

```
C:\directory\filename
```